# How to connect to Pluggable-Database user Directly

Tags: oracle

I'm facing problem to access pluggable databse directly.
I'm trying to login using this command. `sqlplus scott/tiger@pdborcl;` but it return me

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I tried to logged in with `sqlplus scott/tiger@localhost/pdborcl;` but it return me different error.

> ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested
>   in connect descriptor

After that I logged in as `SYSTEM` and I used this command `conn scott/tiger@localhost/pdborcl;` then I successfully logged in. I want to know why I can't login to Pluggable-database without logging to SYSTEM?

Comment: Does `tnsnames.ora` contain an entry for the PDB in addition to the CDB entry?

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli Yes..